# Determining phase portrait of the following systems of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following systems of ODE$$x'=x-3y$$ $$y'=4x-6y$$ Draw its phase portraits

First i calculate the eigenvalue to be -3 and -2. Hence both eigenvalues are real and negative. And the phase portrait is supposed to be a nodal sink. However when i plot the equations on the computer, the computer plot shows a portrait of a degenerate critical point instead. From what i know a degenerate critical point only has one eigenvalue as both eigenvalues are equal, which is clearly not the case for this equation. Thus im cofused. Could anyone please explain. Thanks

Comment: Could you tell a little more about why you think that you see a degenerate critical point? Maybe, you can attach a plot?

Comment: http://www.math.missouri.edu/~bartonae/pplane.html

Comment: This is the plot that i got

Comment: Well, in short, the tool from this page doesn't have a good resolution to see main features of this linear system. This happens because eigenspaces of this system are too close to each other: lines $y = x$ and $y = \frac{4}{3} x $ are really close. You just don't see the eigenspace $y = \frac{4}{3} x $ so it seems to you that everything is tangent to $y = x$ (as in degenerate sink), but it's just an artifact of plotting tool. Try this, for example: http://onlinesciencetools.com/tools/phaseportrait?dx=x%20-%203*y&dy=4*x%20-%206*y&x0=3&y0=0&conc=10 . It allows you to plot multiple trajectories.

Comment: So it should be a nodal sink? But then again its very close to a degenerate critical point. It also appears that a degenerate critical point isnt wrong either. Thus im unsure whether it the correct plot (correct plot as in just based purely on theory alone without using any plotting tool) should look more like a degenerate critical point or a nodal sink. Under such circumstances it becomes diffcult to distinguish between the two.

Comment: First, it's not good to rely solely on sketch of vector field. Usually it just don't have enough details. Second, it's  better to draw samples of trajectories, because perception of them works better than looking at vector field alone. In this case if you took initial conditions at $(3,3)$ and at $(3, 4)$ you'll see that you have two trajectories which are non-tangent at origin -- so, no degenerate nodal sink is possible.

Comment: It does not matter what the initial conditions are?  For example we can take initial conditions $(1,1)$ or $(1,0)$ and the results would still be the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23396/discussion-between-evgeny-and-ys-wong).